# Trying to echo html, and getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in

Tags: php, html, parse-error

I need to echo html (which also contains a variable) and I keep getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

```
while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo '<h1 align = "center"><strong>Section:</strong></h1>.''.'<h1align="center"><strong>$line1   ['section_id']</strong></h1>';}
```

Basically, I need it to read Section: (and then whatever is retrived for Section ID, all on one line). What is the best way to go about outputting html is a situation lke this?

Comment: As you can see by the syntax hilighting in your post, the second header is not quoted. Your php is parsing it and messing it up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499707/how-to-get-rid-of-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-stri)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a trainwreck. Try this:

```
while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<h1 align = "center"><strong>Section:</strong></h1><h1 align="center"><strong>' . $line1['section_id'] . '</strong></h1>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo '<h1 align = "center"><strong>Section:</strong></h1><h1align="center">    <strong>' . $line1 . ' ' .  ['section_id'] .'</strong></h1>';}
```

there you go

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. It looks much better now. The only thing that still isn't working is that the variable (section id) is being dropped to the next line. Is there any way to make it display as one continuous line? Thanks again

Comment: you would have to use an html inline element (span,..) to achieve that or set the css for h1 to "display:inline;". Whenever you use a block element and let it be displayed as such there will be a visible line break.